# Wait for atom change with timeout

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to do something like a `(Thread/sleep millis my-atom)` that would wake up in case `my-atom` got changed before millis?

Or do I have to go `clojure.core.async` for that, using channels instead of watches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a [`promise`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise), using [`deref`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) with a timeout:

```
(def p (promise))
(future ;; some other thread starts working with the promise
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (deliver p :finished-early))
(deref p 1000 :timed-out) ;; => :finished-early
```

If the sleep took longer than `1000` then `deref` would return `:timed-out`.

Update: I see your question is now more specifically about atoms. In that case, you could still use a promise by adding a *watch* on the atom and delivering on the promise if the value changes:

```
(def p (promise))
(def a (atom {}))
(add-watch a :watch-changed
           (fn [_ _ old new]
             (when-not (= old new) (deliver p :changed))))
(future
  (Thread/sleep 1001)
  (swap! a assoc :foo 1))
(deref p 1000 :timed-out) ;; => :changed
```

Or in reusable function form, `r` can be any IRef type:

```
(defn await-change [r timeout-ms]
  (let [p (promise)]
    (try
      (add-watch r :await-change ;; keyword must be unique per ref!
                 (fn [_ _ old new]
                   (when-not (= old new) (deliver p :changed))))
      (deref p timeout-ms :timed-out)
      (finally
        (remove-watch r :await-change)))))

(def a (atom {}))
(future
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (swap! a assoc :foo 1))
(await-change a 1000) ;; => :changed
```

Comment: Yeah, I initially wrote "watches", although what I meant was "atoms". I didn't know about the timeout variant of `deref`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution that repeatedly sleeps for a short interval and calls `break-f` in-between the sleeps to check if it should wake up and return.

In case of an atom, it can e.g. be used like `(interruptible-sleep 100 #(not @my-atom))`

Polling isn't that nice of a concept, but it sometimes suffices:

```
(defn interruptible-sleep
  ([millis break-f] (interruptible-sleep millis break-f 100))
  ([millis break-f polling-millis]
   (if (> millis 0)
     (let [end (+ (System/currentTimeMillis) millis)]
       (loop []
         (let [now (System/currentTimeMillis)
               remaining-millis (- end now)]
           (if (and (> remaining-millis 0) (not (break-f)))
             (do
               (if (>= remaining-millis 5)
                 (Thread/sleep (min polling-millis remaining-millis)))
               (recur))
             (- remaining-millis))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

While the solution using a `promise` is nice, a promise can be set only once and is thereafter immutable. So, it is not a drop-in replacement for an `atom` in your problem.

What might be a better solution is to stick with an `atom` and then [use the `add-watch` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch) to assign a watcher who will be notified whenever the value of the atom changes:

```
(def a (atom {}))

(add-watch a :watcher
  (fn [key atom old-state new-state]
    (prn "-- Atom Changed --")
    (prn "key" key)
    (prn "atom" atom)
    (prn "old-state" old-state)
    (prn "new-state" new-state)))

(reset! a {:foo "bar"})
```

with results:

```
"-- Atom Changed --"
"key"        :watcher
"atom"       #<Atom@4b020acf: {:foo "bar"}>
"old-state"  {}
"new-state"  {:foo "bar"} 

{:foo "bar"}
```

Your code would need to be re-architected a bit, so instead of calling `deref` with a timeout, you would register your code as a callback function.  You could use a `future` or `core/async` to take action if the atom is not changed before the desired timeout.